How to reproduce horizontal flow layout as custom layout in embed.diagrams.net / draw.io?
I would like to programmatically trigger a layout operation for diagrams.net.
I would like to use the horizontal flow layout that is available in the ui and as style:
style="childLayout=flowLayout;flowOrientation=west;"

However, for the api there is no type mxFHorizontalFlowLayout.
=> How to reproduce the horizontal flow layout specified as style, based on the supported layout types?
=> Or how can I trigger an update of the layout, based on the already specified style? (Unfortunately, draw.io does not apply the style automatically but only after manual edits.)
I tried to use mxHierarchicalLayout but I get different results.
        /* available layouts:
        https://www.drawio.com/doc/faq/apply-layouts#custom-layouts

        0 : "mxHierarchicalLayout"
        1 : "mxCircleLayout"
        2 : "mxCompactTreeLayout"
        3 : "mxEdgeLabelLayout"
        4 : "mxFastOrganicLayout"
        5 : "mxParallelEdgeLayout"
        6 : "mxPartitionLayout"
        7 : "mxRadialTreeLayout"
        8 : "mxStackLayout
        */

   function sendLayoutMessage() {{
        // tries to apply a horizontal flow layout
        console.log('layout');
        var iframe = document.getElementById('drawio-iframe');
        var layoutMessage = JSON.stringify({{
            action: 'layout',
            layouts: [
                {{
                    "layout": "mxHierarchicalLayout",
                    "config": {{
                      "orientation": "west",
                      "intraCellSpacing": 0.1,
                      "interRankCellSpacing": 0.1,
                      "interHierarchySpacing": 0.1,
                      "parallelEdgeSpacing": 0.1
                    }}                       
                }}
            ]
        }});
        iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(layoutMessage, '*');
    }}


a) It makes a difference for the layout, if the grid is enabled or not in the mxGraphModel. Disabling the grid by removing the parameter grid="1" helped to reproduce the layout.
b) The flow layout in diagrams.net is implemented based on mxHierarchicalLayout by the script app.min.js with following execution stack:
    mxGraphHandler.prototype.moveCells
    mxGraphModel.prototype.endUpdate
    mxLayoutManager.prototype.beforeUndo
    mxLayoutManager.prototype.executeLayoutForCells
    mxLayoutManager.prototype.layoutCells
    mxLayoutManager.prototype.executeLayout 
    mxHierarchicalLayout.prototype.execute

and following parameters:
    deterministic: true
    interHierarchySpacing: 60
    interRankCellSpacing: 100
    intraCellSpacing: 30
    maintainParentLocation: true
    orientation: "west"
    parallelEdgeSpacing: 10
    parentBorder: 20
    resizeParent: true

